# store password in cloud9 environment

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, cloud9

I started to use cloud9 and use Python code like this:

```
from getpass4 import getpass

DB_PASSWORD = getpass('Password: ')
```

This is suboptimal. Is there a way to store credentials in a cloud9 environment without pushing/committing them to git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't store passwords in Cloud9 and you neither have to push then to Git. The recommended way of storing secrets is to use an integration from another service from AWS.

AWS provides multiple services for storing credentials, for example:

- [AWS SSM Parameter store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html): you can use it for storing clean text parameters and for encrypted secrets as well
- [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html): used for storing secrets in key-value format

Comment: thanks. which of these is easier to use from Python in cloud9. In windows I usually store credentials in environment variables.

Comment: Both of them have similar APIs. In AWS nothing is really free of charge. I suggest looking at the price first. SSM standard parameters are free, but you will have to pay 1$/month for the KMS key. If you will have a lot of secrets, you may want to use this. For Secrets Manager, you pay $0.4/month per secret (it has a free trial), but you can store multiple key/value pairs per secret.